Google Play Console rejected app review BUT not receiving emails/dashboard notification
On 21st of April we transferred an unpublished app from one account to the current one. The transfer was successful and we were able to push new versions out to Internal Testing with no issues.
At the end of May we decided to publish Release version and were awaiting a review, but more than 2 weeks passed and no review info was received. We reached out for help and one of the Product experts found out that our review was in fact rejected due to issues which is fair
The issue is, we did not receive any emails in regards to rejection with instructions that we meant to get AND there were no signs of Rejection on our Google Play Console dashboard.
We have updated the email (even though we are 100% confident that the previous one was robust and was not blocking incoming messages at all) but still no luck.
So it looks like that during the "transfer" process, something was not set corretly from Google's side.
We have contacted support via email and the first reply we received was in regards to Policy Management, and the suggestion to report to them via "Appeal" but we cannot do it as we have nothing in our Policy status section. Once we replied to that first email, we are hearing nothing for last 4 days.
We have tried other means of contact to support, but the "Live Chat" button is just permanent grey/inactive for last month. The "Book a phone call" button is not working ie.e. errors on press but it seems like it is broken for last year (lots of thread on internet) and no one seems to care.
Are there any other ways to contact support to get some feedback, preferably human-made feedback, as we need a conversation not a reply created from a "flow chart" of suggestion.
